# Создание нового .csv на основе данных другого .csv

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, csv

Мне необходимо взять некоторые данные из input.csv и далее создать output.csv.

Беру данные по некоторым полям + в одно из полей output.csv добавил свой текст:

```
import pandas as pd

(pd.read_csv(r'E:/input.csv', usecols=[' column1', column2', column3', column4'], sep=';', skipinitialspace=True)
       .to_csv(r'E:/output1.csv', sep=';', header=False, index=False))
```

Между `column3` и `column4` необходимо в новое поле вставить указанный текст `"тест"`, и над полем `column3` выполнить расчет, простое деление на 10 (`column3 - float`).

Прошу совета, как обновить мой код?

Answer (score 3):

Можно сделать так:

```
(pd.read_csv(r'E:/input.csv', usecols=['column1', 'column2', 'column3', 'column4'], 
             sep=';', skipinitialspace=True)
 .eval("column3 = column3 / 10\ntest='test'")
 ['column1', 'column2', 'column3', 'test', 'column4']
 .to_csv(r'E:/output1.csv', sep=';', header=False, index=False))
```

Answer (score 2):

Вам нужно:

1. Присвоить считанный DataFrame в какую-то переменную

   df = pd.read_csv(...)
2. Добавить колонку в DataFrame

   df['new_column'] = 'тест'
3. Отсортировать нужным образом колонки в DataFrame

   df = df[['column1', 'column2', 'column3', 'new_column', 'column4']]
4. Разделить column3 на 10

   df['column3'] = df['column3'] / 10
5. Сохранить получившийся DataFrame

   df.to_csv(...)

Comment: вместо пунктов 2 и 3 можно сделать `df.insert(3, 'new_column', 'test')` ;)